# ColdFusion error - String index out of range: 0

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The following code in my ColdFusion 9 app on windows 7 is giving the above error. The textbox with the name available_balance has a default value as $0.00. Only if user removes this value and click on Submit button, this above error occurs:

```
<cfif (isDefined('form.available_balance') AND (#LSIsCurrency(trim(form.available_balance))# neq ""))>
    <cfset available_balance = "#replace(replace(trim(form.available_balance),'$','','All'), ',', '')#">        
</cfif>
```

Comment: Depending on your overall requirements, you could make the form fields mandatory.

Comment: Tip: When you see a function name like ***Is**Something*, it usually means the function returns true/false - not a string.  As you would expect, *LS**IsCurrency*** returns true if the input is considered valid (locale specific) currency and false if it is not.  Also, nothing to do with your question, but none of the pound signs in the code are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> **LSIsCurrency** doesn't take empty string or string with spaces only as
>   input. Returns **boolean** value.

So, you can try this:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "available_balance")> 
  <cfset form.available_balance = trim(form.available_balance)> 
  <cfif len(form.available_balance) AND LSIsCurrency(form.available_balance)>
    <cfset form.available_balance = LSParseCurrency(form.available_balance)>
  </cfif>      
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was causing the issue.